# how we can add a value in replace function in regular expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a `string="2 HOUR PARKING 7AM-6PM"` and I wrote the following regular expression:

```
var string = "2 HOUR PARKING 7AM-6PM"
var reg =new RegExp(/([0-9])AM\-([0-9])PM/ig);
string = string.replace(reg,"$1-$2")
```

this results to **`2 HOUR PARKING 7-6`**, BUT I would like to have a result like **`2 HOUR PARKING 7-18`** since 6 pm means 18:00 o'clock. How can I add a number to $2 dynamically while it is replacing?
I even tried this one:

```
string = string.replace(eg,"$1-$2\+12")
```

but replace function treats it as a string and the result is `2 HOUR PARKING 7-6\+12`

That would be great if someone could help me.
Thanks

Comment: Try `string.replace(reg,function($0,$1,$2) {
      return $1 + "-" + (12 + parseInt($2,10));
    })` with `/\b(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])AM-(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])PM/ig` regex

Comment: I tried but it does not work. could you please explain the function($0.$1,$2) a bit? thanks

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/n29r0j8u/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [pass in a function to the string `replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) parameter to compute the 24 hour value for the times.

```js
function convertTime(time, ampm) {
  time = parseInt(time);

  if (ampm.toUpperCase() === "PM")
    time += 12;

  return time;
}

var str = "2 HOUR PARKING 7AM-9PM";
var reg = new RegExp(/([0-9]+)(AM|PM)-([0-9]+)(AM|PM)$/i);

str = str.replace(reg, function(match, from, fromP, to, toP) {
  return convertTime(from, fromP) + "-" + convertTime(to, toP);
});

console.log(str);
```

Comment: May I ask you what is the role of $ in the definition of regular expression? in this line : var reg = new RegExp(/([0-9]+)(AM|PM)-([0-9]+)(AM|PM)$/i);

Comment: $ is to match the end of the line. i.e. it will only match the time representation at the end of the input string. It might not be necessary if the same pattern wont be repeated earlier in the string.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. the answer from Wiktor Stribiżew seems to be correct but it does not work. I could not figure it out where is the problem. Could please tell me what is actually wrong in this code?

Comment: It passes in the matched groups as parameters into the function. Maybe something is going wrong there?